# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geventwebsocket'

Tags: python, heroku, flask, websocket, gunicorn

Can't run my web-socket site on Heroku cloud with gunicorn. Locally ('heroku local') its working fine, but when i try to acess my site URL it gets crashed.

Logs:

> 2018-07-18T20:45:32.563241+00:00 app[web.1]: **Error: class uri 'geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker' invalid or not found:**
>
> 2018-07-18T20:45:32.563242+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-07-18T20:45:32.563244+00:00 app[web.1]: [Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> 2018-07-18T20:45:32.563246+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 132, in load_class
>
> 2018-07-18T20:45:32.563247+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = import('.'.join(components))
>
> 2018-07-18T20:45:32.563249+00:00 app[web.1]: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geventwebsocket'**
>
> 2018-07-18T20:45:32.563250+00:00 app[web.1]: ]

Comment: You probably need to install **gevent-websocket**: `pip install gevent-websocket`

Comment: I already instaled it. Actually, "heroku local" command and localhost works.

Comment: It seems like geventwebsocket module directory isn't in heroku app folder, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 4):

The package name is as mentioned `gevent-websocket`, so it's

```
conda activate <env-name>
conda install gevent-websocket
```

or

```
pip install gevent-websocket
```

depending if you use anaconda or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If problem not in gevent-websocket, then probably you installed gunicorn with `apt`, try also installing with `pip`:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

If you're working under virtual environment, deactivate and activate again.

```
deactivate
conda activate <env-name>
```

or (Linux)

```
deactivate
source path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

or (Windows)

```
deactivate
path\to\venv\Scripts\activate
```